# Table rate (Weight vs Destionation with a message if weight above 5 kg)

Tags: magento-1.9, table-rates, messages

i have tried to show some message like contact the provider if the weight greater then 5 kg using the table rate in magento.

If i give the message in excel it's not uploading

Anyone help me with it

Comment: Maybe I understand the question wrong, but Magento doesn't support this function?

Answer (score 2):

Basically you want to restrict shipping of packages with weight greater than 5kg.
If you don't want to use shipping restriction module from the magento connect, then you need to extend the table rates class `app\code\core\Mage\Shipping\Model\Carrier\Tablerate.php` and update method `collectRates` like below:

```
...
if ($request->getPackageWeight() > 5){
        $error = $this->_getModel('shipping/rate_result_error');
        $error->setCarrier('tablerate');
        $error->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));
        $error->setErrorMessage('Please contact the provider');
        $result->append($error);
        return $result; 
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

As Fabian indicates this is supported in Magento.

With Magento tablerates you can output a single error message if rates cannot be found. No coding required. Its explicitly in all magento carriers e.g.

[image]

Just setup the csv file so that no rates are provider over 5Kg and then set the 'Show Method if not Available' to Yes, and specify an error message. This will then be output. Note: on versions of Magento I think prior to 1.7 this didn't work, I fixed it during a great Magento hackathon in Switzerland.

[image]

If you need to change the error message based on the particular rule in the csv that has failed I suggest you extend the tablerates extension and add an extra column to store the error message. You can then explicitly set this.

Comment: Karen, doesn't it work in opposite way? As far as I know rate is matched if item weight is equal or greater. It would mean that it isn't possible to hide method for cart with weight greater than particular one, 5kg in this case. It could be possible to set up tablerate in way to not display method if cart weight is lower than 5kg.

Comment: Ah okay, I never use tablerates itself anymore as we have a free extension Matrixrates that I've used since 2008, apologies, I didn't realise it was that bad!! I'd suggest put on Matrixrates, you can set a weight range then, so the whole issue goes away. You can download under free stuff on WebShopApps.com. Drop us a line and I'll send you an example csv.

Comment: Karen, I also use Matrixrates for years and I can confirm that use case mentioned in question can be handled properly there.